# Parallel serialization in Django REST Framework? Or other methods of speeding up model serialization?

Tags: python, django, multithreading, django-rest-framework, multiprocessing

The app I'm developing needs to deliver a list of ORM objects to the user via a REST endpoint. The list of objects is large - up to 500 or 600 at a time (pagination is not an option).

The model looks something like this:

```
class PositionItem(models.Model):
    account = models.ForeignKey(core_models.Portfolio, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    macro_category = models.ForeignKey(MacroCategory, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    sub_category = models.ForeignKey(SubCategory, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

I started using a standard `ModelSerializer` with `many=True` set, but it was very slow - taking up to 12 seconds to serialize all the objects. I decreased the run time by a few seconds by pre-fetching/caching foreign keys needed for the endpoint with the `.select_related()` method, and another couple seconds by replacing the `ModelSerializer` with a custom serializer function that just maps the fields to a dictionary with none of the validation overhead. However, it's still slow (6-7 seconds) and I'd like to optimize further. I thought about trying to parallelize the serializer instead, but am having some problems implementing.

My custom serializer looks like this:

```
def serialize_position_record(record):

    account = record.account
    macro_category = record.macro_category
    category = record.category
    sub_category = record.sub_category

    return {
        'account': account.portfolio_id,
        'macro_category': macro_category.macro_category,
        'category': category.category,
        'sub_category': sub_category.sub_category,
        'sorting': {
            'macro_category': macro_category.sort_order,
            'category': category.sort_order,
            'sub_category': sub_category.sort_order

        }
    }
```

I've tried `multiprocessing` with a `Pool`:

```
import multiprocessing
import models
import utils

items = models.Item.objects.select_related().filter(account__user=user)
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(4)
serialized_items = pool.map(utils.serialize_position_record, items)
```

but this hangs for at least 60 seconds (probably more, I killed it before it returned anything).

I also tried threading using the `multiprocessing.dummy` API:

```
import multiprocessing
import models
import utils

items = models.Item.objects.select_related().filter(account__user=user)
pool = multiprocessing.dummy.Pool(4)
serialized_items = pool.map(utils.serialize_position_record, items)
```

but I get exceptions:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xx/venvs/web-portal/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 164, in __get__
    rel_obj = self.field.get_cached_value(instance)
  File "/Users/xx/venvs/web-portal/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/mixins.py", line 13, in get_cached_value
    return instance._state.fields_cache[cache_name]
KeyError: 'sub_category'
```

and

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xx/venvs/web-portal/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "reports_subcategory" does not exist
LINE 1: ...", "reports_subcategory"."sort_order" FROM "reports_s...
```

So I'm at a loss as far as what to do. I don't write a lot of parallel code - am I writing something incorrectly? Or is there a better way to optimize this process besides parallelization? Have I hit the ceiling for performance? I'm also using django-tenants as this is a multi-tenant app - not sure if that's contributing to the relation-doesn't-exist error.

Any ideas?

Comment: https://hakibenita.com/django-rest-framework-slow

Answer (score 2):

Consider using third party serialization libraries such as [serpy](https://github.com/clarkduvall/serpy) and [marshmallow](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). Both claim to provide significant speed improvements over the native Django Rest Framework serializers.

Serpy provides some [detailed benchmarks](https://serpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/performance.html) on their docs.

[image: Serialization Times According to Serpy]

Both libraries are fairly intuitive if you're already familiar with serializers in Django Rest Framework.